# WPF only Binding to auto-implemented Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a label that binds to a property, the binding only works when the property in the view model is auto-implemented.

In XAML:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyProperty}" />
```

In ViewModel:

```
public virtual string MyProperty { get; set; }
//This code above works fine, but when i use it as below,binding doesn't work

private string _myProperty;
public virtual string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set { _myProperty = value; }
}
```

Comment: By 'not working', have you meant it is loading the initial value properly but the label isn't changing upon property update?

Comment: Both are the same. If you mean changing the property triggered a UI update for the auto-property, but not for the explicit implementation, than that’s coincidence or you also changed other parts of code. If you want to trigger UI updates you need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface and notify the UI in the setter. For details see

Comment: i am using mvvm with pocoview models, when using the first approach,the debugger is entering when user changes the label  the OnMyPropertyChahged(); using the second approach its not working

Comment: This seems to be a special feature of DevExpress POCOViewModels (which you should have mentioned you are using) as they are rewriting public virtual auto-implemented properties by creating a subclass behind your back and overwrite these properties with the proper notification code. See [DevExpress’ documentation on POCOViewModels](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/17352/MVVM-Framework/View-Models/POCO-ViewModels#bindableproperties).

Comment: and whats the solution if my purpose is to change the setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using a compile-time code generation utility to handle `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` for you, such as [Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/) or DevExpress. Such tools would handle an auto-implemented property but you'd need to handle your fully-implemented properties by explicitly raising the event after you change property value.

```
private string _myProperty;
public virtual string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set
    {
        _myProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyProperty)); // or however your base view-model class method signature for raising the event
    }
}
```